# Layout file: Please correct the XML data and try again

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

Below is the layout file that i created:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="styles"/>
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <uiComponent name="salesperson_report"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

I have tried multiple things but I am still getting error: Please correct the XML data and try again.

Can anyone find any issue in this.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with xml data type definition. Kindly change

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this might be useful for you.

**From**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

**To**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the content of layout you are using. Layout structure you are using is correct but it seems there is a space in the beginning of xml tag due to which it is showing invalid xml.
Please remove additional space in your layout and then check.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="salesperson_report"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```